# show name of the html file served by the web browser

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to to be able to display in my Javascript console which `home` file the browser has loaded when only the domain name has been typed in the browser address bar (e.g. anydomain.com). Is it `index.html`, `index.php`, `index.htm` ...?

I can't seem to find anything in the DOM that records this. I've tried `document.URL`, `documentURI`, `window.location`, but all of these simply return the domain name in this case.

Is it that this is the server's private business and it doesn't tell the DOM? Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this as your server converts the document to a html page so by the time the browser sees it, it is only html.  I think it would also be more of a security risk if people were able to find out what other websites were written in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it that this is the server's private business and it doesn't tell the DOM?

Yes.

The client asks for a resource at a given URL. The server responds with that resource.

There is generally no information provided about what process the server used to generate that response. It might have read a file, it might have accessed a database, it might have generated it entirely from inside the software of the HTTP server itself, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that. At least I know where I am and I can avoid wasting time looking for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php like this:

`<?php echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);?>` or

```
<?php echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);?>
```