# detect actual page URL and customize

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to detect the actual url of the page and modify the same

Detected URL : http://127.0.0.1:portno/path1/path2/home.html
Expected URL : http://127.0.0.1:portno/path1/path2/home2.html

I have tried the below code

```js
document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = window.location.href;
var urlv = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/path1/path2/home2.html";
document.getElementById("newurl").innerHTML = urlv;
```

```html
<p id="url"></p>
<p id="newurl"></p>
```

I have achieve the above by typing "/path1/path2/home2.html". Is there any way to achieve the same without typing the path manually?

Comment: you can achieve the same using **window.location.pathname**

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, pathname will detect the actual path, but I have to modify the last html page name

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224997/show-name-of-the-html-file-served-by-the-web-browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show name of the html file served by the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224997/show-name-of-the-html-file-served-by-the-web-browser)

Comment: It is not, I'm not able to find the answer which I'm looking for from the above link